# 'The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(4000),@Code int,@Brand nvarchar(4000),@Price int' expects the parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I am new and trying to do REST API and only having trouble adding and updating data through PostMan. Whenever I send this error shows up.

***'The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(4000),@Code int,@Brand nvarchar(4000),@Price int' expects the parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.'***

Here is the code from C#:
**Add and Update**

```
     //Posts new Item then inserted to the database
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("/api/[controller]/additems")]
     public void AddItem(AddItem additem)
     {
         using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
         {
             var query = "INSERT INTO Items (Name, Code, Brand, Price, Quantity) VALUES (@Name, @Code, @Brand, @Price, @Quantity)";

             

             using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
             {
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", additem.Name);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", additem.Code);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", additem.Brand);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", additem.Price);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", additem.Quantity);

                 connection.Open();

                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 
             }
             
         }
         
     }


     //Updates an Item based on Id
     [HttpPut]
     [Route("/api/[controller]/updateitem/{id}")]
     public void UpdateItem(int id, UpdateItem Update)
     {
         using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
         {
             var query = "UPDATE Items SET Name = @Name, Code = @Code, Brand = @Brand, Price = @Price, Quantity = @Quantity WHERE Id = @Id";

             using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
             {
                 connection.Open();


                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Update.Name);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", Update.Code);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", Update.Brand);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Update.Price);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Update.Quantity);

                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 connection.Close();
                 //return Ok("Item updated successfully.");

             }
         }
     }
```

I want to be able to add and update data through PostMan.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to do `command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, some_length_here).Value = additem.Name ?? (object)DBNull.Value;`

Comment: I would [advise against using `AddWithValue()`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and instead always explicitly define your parameter types (as in the comment above) - it's only marginally more typing and worst case will end up with the same query performance, but could end up performing much better so always worth being explicit in my opinion.

Comment: But why doesn't addwithvalue work? This issue is often posted

Comment: Because if you pass null as the value it doesn't send the parameter at all

Comment: Ah, dbnull. So logical but still so not :) Thanks @MartinSmith!